# I'm getting bone heat weighting failed. No previous mentioned solution works

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to rig this character but cannot seem to get it to work.I keep getting bone heat weighting error and I've tried deleting doubles, scaling the model,and any other thing I've come across but alas, nothing works. I'm fairly new to blender so if you find a something that works please be thorough and gentle in explaining it. I'd greatly appreciate if someone could rig it and send that model back to me :)

Blend File:https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfejz30qz17h5d4/RiggHazmat.blend?dl=0

Comment: When I click the link myself it says somethings wrong but there is still a download button at the top that works still. What issue are you having with my link?

Comment: The suit in the file you've posted has duplicate vertices, interior faces, and non-manifold geometry, all of which would make it difficult for automatic weights to work. But it also doesn't have an armature to use in rigging the suit.  Could you go back to a version where you have an armature that's not working and post it instead?

Comment: Yes your link works, I don't know why there was an error message, but as Marty says, the armature is not here

Comment: My apologies, I'm correcting the file now.

Comment: Okay I have the right link up now. I'm sorry guys

Comment: FWIW, I suspect that "something went wrong" because Dropbox checks blend files but is having similar problems to the ones blend-exchange was having wrt recognizing blend files from recent versions of Blender.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale of your armature, select the mesh, switch to *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* with a *Distance* of 0.001, it may remove some vertices but it will fix your problem.